# Remove all <br> tags from within a string – not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried a dozen of solutions and nothing seem to help.

HTML:

```
<div class="mont-text-content mobile">С чего следует начинать запуск своего бизнеса.
    <br><br>Как и где находить идеи для бизнеса.
    <br><br>Как справляться со своими страхами и обрушивающейся критикой родных, друзей и знакомых. Когда вам говорят, что ничего не получится?
    <br><br>Как понять, что вам действительно следует ступать на путь предпринимательства и заниматься бизнесом, а не работать на дядю с 9 до 18.
    <br><br>Как себя мотивировать и находить силы, чтобы не сдаться?
    <br><br>На все эти и другие вопросы вы найдете ответы на нашем юридическом бизнес-вебинаре.</div>

<div class="mont-text-content mobile">Правильный выбор видов деятельности и организационно-правовой формы вашего будущего бизнеса является очень важным фактором.
    <br><br>Во-первых, для легализации деятельности, возможности открытого взаимодействия с государственными и частными органами, контрагентами, инвесторами и пр., оптимизации операций, которые подлежат налогообложению.
    <br><br>А во-вторых, для возможности действовать в рамках правового поля, используя законодательство в качестве мощного инструмента для защиты и развития своего бизнеса.
    <br><br>Вы узнаете, в чём состоит отличие ФЛП на 1 группе от 2 и 3 групп. А также какая организационно-правовая форма, по состоянию на сегодня, является самой оптимальной и менее «затратной» для бизнеса.</div>
```

JS:

```
$( ".mont-text-content.mobile" ).each(function( index ) {
    let content = $(this).text();
    let newContent = content.replace(/^(\s*<br\s*\/?\s*>\s*)*|(\s*<br\s*\/?\s*>\s*)*\s*$/g, '');
    alert( index + ": " + newContent );
});
```

And here is a link to a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2j5830z1/)

As you can see, the `<br>` tags are converted into strange uni-code characters and are not being removed from the string.

Comment: replace the innerHTML instead of the text(). pay attention to case and closing.

Comment: `.mont-text-content.mobile br {
  display: none;
}`

Comment: That's interesting. I usually see people on Stack Overflow reflexively using `innerHTML` for everything, even when it's plain text (or might not be, but they definitely don't want entities and tags parsed) they're assigning, instead of considering `innerText` or `textContent`.

Comment: @dandavis yea, now the `<br>` tags are there, still the regex is not working. Would you mind pointing me to the the issue? @j08691 - I need to do a couple more things with this string so just hiding it with CSS won't help in this case.

Comment: Your reg ex ends with `\s*$` so will only remove `<br/>` at the end of the line (excluding whitespace) just remove the `$` and all;s good.  https://jsfiddle.net/c46guqpy/

Comment: The "strange unicode characters" are how the `alert()` shows the `tab`s at the beginning of each line and not related to the `<br>`s in anyway.

Comment: makes no sense to match DOM with a regular expression.  Why not just `$('.mont-text-content br').remove();` or hide it with css

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks a lot! Rechecked my regex on regex101 and found a few issues, one of which you pointed out.

Comment: Seems like a lot of unnecessary effort to “remove” html elements when you can simply collapse them using CSS as per comment by @j08691

Comment: @Cue I just need the strings so I can create "preview" elements for mobile. I don't want to remove the <br> tags globally for this div because I still need them when user decides to "read more".

Comment: @Ricardo if that’s the case, with your regex removing html elements, wouldn’t you then have to add the elements again when a user reads more? Using CSS your simply controlling visibility, which effectively simulated what your JavaScript is achieving, but without removing the nodes. You could just toggle a class which toggles visibility of the line breaks... unless I’m misunderstanding your question here.

Comment: @Cue that's a perspective I didn't think about. Very useful, I will definitely try tomorrow. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this though i'm not sure if this will be most effective :

```
 var x =    $( ".mont-text-content.mobile" ).html();
 var res = x.replace('<br>',"");
 $(".mont-text-content.mobile" ).html(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this sorry for replacing with random text it's just to be more clear.

```js
$(".mont-text-content.mobile").each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\<br>/g, ""));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mont-text-content mobile">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
  <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
  <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
  <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
  <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
  <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>

<div class="mont-text-content mobile">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
  <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
  <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
  <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply some way like this one:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.mont-text-content').forEach((divElm) => {
    Array.from(divElm.children).forEach((elm) => {
        if (elm.tagName === 'BR') {
            elm.remove();
        }
    });
});
```

It is in ES6. But it is easy to rewrite to ES5.

In first I finded all elements with class name and than itinerate these elements in forEach loop.

Next is needed convert List of HTML elemets to array and go throw the array and remove the element if it is a br tag.